# Count number of bit in hexdecimal using C file and while

Tags: c, while-loop

How to count number  of bits in the variable **GH** that have value of 1 and assigns the results to the variable **CT** using while loop ?

```
 int main(void)
 {
      unsigned int GT = 0x12345678;
      unsigned int CT = 0;

      < The solution >

      all_done: return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer

Answer (score 0):

Use bitwise shift `<<` or `>>` to move a single `1` from top to bottom (or opposite), and use that as a mask to check if the corresponding bit in `GT` is set. Increase the counter variable if a bit is set.